# Selenium | Unable to locate the element error

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I've used many locator combinations but still, I'm getting element not found error. Here's the element

```
<div id="mailmillieu">
  <div>
   <div style="padding:8px"></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    Hi, here is your otp :  216570
  </div>
</div>
```

I just want to extract the otp, that's all. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#mailmillieu > div:nth-child(2)` css locator and then use getText() on it.
On the string you get you can then extract out numbers to get the OTP value.

Comment: I've tried it earlier, but still I'm getting the error org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#mailmillieu > div:nth-child(2)"}

Comment: @sparshbhardwaj Can you check if you are in correct frame?

Comment: I believe I am in correct frame. But I'm not sure what you mean by frame

Comment: <iframe> tag  is there an element above with this tag.

Comment: If this code in inside iframe, switch to frame first then read the value. https://www.guru99.com/handling-iframes-selenium.html